# Can Anchoring Arcana be used with Rune of the Eldritch Knight?

Tags: magic-items, starfinder

From the [SFSRD](http://www.starfindersrd.com/classes/soldier/) (*emphasis mine*):

> **Anchoring Arcana (Su)**
>   As a full action, you can make a single attack with a *magic weapon* against a single foe. ...

So if you have a magic weapon, you can make a special attack.

> **Rune of the Eldritch Knight (Su)**
>   You can imbue a weapon with a magic sigil, the rune of the eldritch knight, allowing the weapon to *act as a magic weapon* for the purposes of bypassing DR and affecting incorporeal creatures. This takes 10 minutes, and you can imbue only a single weapon at a time. If you imbue a new weapon with the rune of the eldritch knight, any previously imbued weapon loses this benefit. When calculating the Hit Points and hardness of a weapon imbued with the rune of the eldritch knight, treat its item level as 5 higher.

So you can make a non-magic weapon count as a magic weapon.

Can a weapon imbued with Rune of the Eldritch Knight be used to make an Anchoring Arcana attack?

**NOTE:** A straightforward reading of the abilities would suggest that they *can't* be used together, since RotEK only makes a weapon count as magic for certain explicitly-defined purposes that do not include Anchoring Arcana. However it seems odd that soldiers would have an ability that requires a magic weapon and an ability that makes a weapon count as magic but that those abilities wouldn't work together. Therefore I am primarily interested in **statements from the designers** regarding whether these features are *intended* to work together.

Comment: There is not a single topic about this on paizo.com, that isn't a character build or threads discussing those abilities individually during the beta period. Which suggests this is not something that has been questioned before (probably due to the wording of those abilities suggesting they don't work together) Maybe the first approach should be creating a thread asking this question *there*.

Comment: [Designer reasons questions are generally off-topic](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7964/are-questions-about-rule-intent-on-topic) - but I don't think you're asking about the reasoning behind the rules so much as you are simply asking if this is how the rules are meant to be interpreted, so the question itself should be fine. (Though maybe the "designer-reasons" tag should be removed?)

Answer (score 1):

The [Anchoring Arcana Gear Boost](http://www.starjammersrd.com/classes/soldier/#Anchoring_Arcana_Su_7th_level) is not part of the [Arcane Assailant fighting style](http://www.starjammersrd.com/classes/soldier/#Arcane_Assailant) and currently does not synergyise.
Like you said, this does feel like an oversight and I would be surprised if the next official version of Anchoring Arcana will read something along the lines of

> As a full action, you can make a single attack with a magic weapon or a weapon imbued with the rune of the eldritch knight against a single foe. [...]

Until then it's up to the individual GMs, but I'd be surprised if they wouldn't rule in favour of the two working together.
As the comment you received pointed out already, there is currently no official statement or other discussion about this, so this is primarily just me backing up what you were already saying yourself (sorry).